# savedinstancestate for text change with spinner

Tags: android

So I have a spinner that allows the user to select a language, (e.g. english, spanish, french). When clicked it changes the text on the screen to the respective language selected. The text changes as expected and even in screen rotation. The problem however, if I click the home button on my phone that temporarily closes out of the app or if I shut off the screen on my phone. Whenever I reopen the app, it doesn't save my selection of language choice, if I had it clicked on spanish or french, it reverts back to english and the spinner still has the selected language.

How can I save the selection in this particular case?

```
langSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Spanish")){
                questionTxt.setText(questionSpanishTxt);
                Log.e("langSpin", "onItemSelected: spanish");
            }

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("French")){
                questionTxt.setText(questionFrenchTxt);
                Log.e("langSpin", "onItemSelected: french");
            }

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("English")){
                questionTxt.setText(questionEnglishTxt);
                Log.e("langSpin", "onItemSelected: english");
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Recreating an Activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) goes over this in detail

Answer (score 1):

Keep your position in a instance variable. Assign last position when activity onResume.

```
int position=0; // Default
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    langSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {

            position=pos; // Assign position as "latest"

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("Spanish")){
                questionTxt.setText(questionSpanishTxt);
                Log.e("langSpin", "onItemSelected: spanish");
            }

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("French")){
                questionTxt.setText(questionFrenchTxt);
                Log.e("langSpin", "onItemSelected: french");
            }

            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("English")){
                questionTxt.setText(questionEnglishTxt);
                Log.e("langSpin", "onItemSelected: english");
            }
        }
        *
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "position" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    langSpin.setSelection(position);   // Set latest position 
    questionTxt.setText(langSpin.getSelectedItem().toString()); // Set text from spinner selection.
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: I feel like implementing `onSaveInstanceState()` is a safer approach

Comment: I got excited for a second, this almost works.. So when I go back into the app it shows the toast message but it doesn't keep the text changed, it still reverts to the default english selection

Comment: Because we didn't change. I added a line to onResume, you can set text after setselection. Check out the  answer.

If it's ok, mark as solved

Comment: Okay cool man, I'm away from my computer for the weekend but as soon as I get back to it, I'll try this out. My only concern in trying you code, before you edited it, is that it broke the onConfigurationChange(in that it switches the text back to default) which previously wasn't given me any problems

Comment: no this didn't work. It breaks the onConfigurationChange and it doesn't store the translated language selection. When I come back to app, it's only changing the text to that of the language title, like Spanish or French